# onclick zoom image in full screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have slider wth product image, there is a button `view more`. I want that when someone clicks on that button then image of that product should be visible/zoomed to full screen with animation. Just like this:

> https://dribbble.com/shots/6347184-Better-Hero -- Example link

My header screenshot:
[image]
**My code:**

```
<div class="projectSlider"> // slider
    <div class="projectSlider--item"> // slider item 1
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="projectSlider--text">
                    <div class="projectSlider--subTitle">An Inspirational Collection Of</div>
                    <div class="projectSlider--title"><span>Creative Designs</span></div>
                    <p class="projectSlider--description">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
                        incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                    </p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn secondary projectSlider--view" data-quickview="quickView">View
                        More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="projectSlider--img">
                    <img src="img/template.jpg" alt="template"> // slider image
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    // slider items, so on....
</div>
```

I don't know how to do that kind of image zoom effect. Can you please help me with this? I m stuck

Comment: What you are looking for could be made with something called a "modal". There are a lot of JS libraries out there, searching for "modal library" should give you plenty of options to choose from.

Comment: no, modal is something new content, My boss don't want me to make modal.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating a simple animation which increases the image size, and after, creating a click listener on that image.

Take a look at the following example, which increases the image size by clicking on it.

```js
        const image = document.querySelector(".clickable-image");

        image.addEventListener("click", () =>{
            image.classList.add("image-open");
        })
```

```css
.clickable-image{
  width:50vw;
}

.image-open{
  animation: scaleUp 2s forwards linear;
}

.clickable-image:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
}

@keyframes scaleUp{
  from{
    width:50vw;
  }to{
    width:100vw;
  }
}
```

```html
    <img class="clickable-image" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ea/e4/a5/eae4a5191fafae3979ea975d206fcd0b.jpg" alt="image">
```

Comment: Hum... I didn't quite understand your requirment then... You didn't mean to scale up the image when clicking on a button?

Comment: Actually I have attached example link in my question. you can check that link